# Reindex Pyspark Dataframe with dates in Year-Week format for each group

Tags: python, date, pyspark, group-by, reindex

I have the following Pyspark dataframe:

```
id1  id2   date         col1    col2 
1     1    2022-W01      5       10
1     2    2022-W02      2       5
1     3    2022-W03      3       8
1     5    2022-W05      5       3
2     2    2022-W03      2       2
2     6    2022-W05      4       1
2     8    2022-W07      3       2
```

I would like to fill the missing dates for each id1 and obtain something like this:

```
id1  id2   date         col1    col2 
1     1    2022-W01      5       10
1     2    2022-W02      2       5
1     3    2022-W03      3       8
1     NA   2022-W04      NA      NA
1     5    2022-W05      5       3
2     2    2022-W03      2       2
2     NA   2022-W04      NA      NA
2     6    2022-W05      4       1
12    NA   2022-W06      NA      NA
2     8    2022-W07      3       2
```

I started with this code:

```
df.groupby('id').agg(F.expr('max(date)').alias('max_date'),F.expr('min(date)').alias('min_date'))\
   .withColumn('date',F.expr("explode(sequence(min_date,max_date,interval 1 week))"))\
   .drop('max_date','min_date')
  )
```

The main problem is that my date is in a particular format '2022-W01'. I couldn't find a quick solution for it

Answer (score 1):

```
r= regexp_extract('date','\d$',0 )
w=Window.partitionBy('id1')
new = (
          df.withColumn('y', min(r).over(w).astype('int'))
            .withColumn('x', max(r).over(w).astype('int'))
          #extract trailing digits in date, use min and max to create sequence, use array except to find missing dates' digits
          .withColumn('z', array_except(sequence(col('y'), col('x')),collect_list(r.astype('int')).over(w)))
          # explode column generated above
         .withColumn('z',explode('z'))
          #concat missing digits and dates to create new dates
         .withColumn('date',concat(regexp_replace('date', '\d$',''),col('z')))
          # select required columns
          .select('id1','date')
          # drop duplicates
          .dropDuplicates()
        )

#Create new df by appending outcome of above to existing df and sorting
df.unionByName(new, allowMissingColumns=True).sort('id1','date').show()

+---+----+--------+----+----+
|id1| id2|    date|col1|col2|
+---+----+--------+----+----+
|  1|   1|2022-W01|   5|  10|
|  1|   2|2022-W02|   2|   5|
|  1|   3|2022-W03|   3|   8|
|  1|null|2022-W04|null|null|
|  1|   5|2022-W05|   5|   3|
|  2|   2|2022-W03|   2|   2|
|  2|null|2022-W04|null|null|
|  2|   6|2022-W05|   4|   1|
|  2|null|2022-W06|null|null|
|  2|   8|2022-W07|   3|   2|
+---+----+--------+----+----+
```

Comment: Cant understand why. Any see my edits. Does that help> Happy to assist further

Comment: Actually i was able to make it work with the older version, just by using F.min, F.max and cast instead of astype. The only issue is that it works partially, like in some cases i have several missing dates in between, and not all of them get generated. Only some of the dates are generated

Comment: Not sure if it's because in the real dataset I have also W10, W11 and so on, and I also have multiple years

Comment: What about you include suspect dates so that I try from my end?